# UDP Tracker not sending any response

Tags: go, udp, torrent, tracker

I am trying to implement a torrent client in golang using the [UDP Tracker Protocol](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html). I first open a UDP connection and send a **connect** message to the tracker but receive no response in return.

Here's the [complete source code](https://github.com/Ehab-24/torrent-client-udp) and below are the important functions:

***main.go/main() function***

```
    // Path to .torrent file must be provided in the os args
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        log.Fatal("missing required argument \"path\"")
    }
    path := os.Args[1]

    // Read and parse the torrent file
    torrent, err := torrent.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    announceURL, err := url.Parse(torrent.Announce)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    port, err := strconv.Atoi(announceURL.Port())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Create a new Node instance for this client
    node, err := node.New(announceURL.Hostname(), uint16(port))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer node.Close()  // close the under lying UDP connection

    // Send connection message to the tracker
    if err := node.SendConnect(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for runtime.NumGoroutine() > 1 {
    }
```

***node.go/node.New() function***
Creates a new Node for the current client

```
// Dial a connection to the given host
    addr := host + ":" + strconv.Itoa(int(port))
    raddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", addr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    c, err := net.DialUDP("udp4", nil, raddr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Calculate Node's ID
    buf := [2]byte{}
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(buf[:], port)
    sha1Sum := sha1.Sum(append([]byte(host), buf[:]...))
    id := hex.EncodeToString(sha1Sum[:])

    // Create a new Node
    n := &Node{
        ID:      id,
        UDPConn: c,
    }

    // Listen for incoming messages
    readCh := make(chan []byte)
    go n.listen(readCh)

    return n, nil
```

***node.go/node.listen() function***
listens for incoming messages

```
buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        _, err := n.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error while reading from %v ~ %v\n", n.RemoteAddr(), err)
        } else {
            ch <- buf
        }
    }
```

***node.go/process() function***
Do something with the incoming messages

```
for {
        msg := <-ch
        log.Println(string(msg))
    }
```

***node.go/SendConnect() function***
Sends a `connect` message to the tracker

```
var protocolID int64 = 0x41727101980
    var action int32 = 0
    var transactionID int32 = utils.NewTransactionID()  // auto increment integer

    // Create the message as a buffer
    buf := make([]byte, 16) // `Connect` messages are of fixed length
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(buf[:8], uint64(protocolID))
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(buf[8:12], uint32(action))
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(buf[12:16], uint32(transactionID))

    // Send message
    _, err := n.Write(buf)

    return err
```

***go.mod***

```
module github.com/Ehab-24/torrent-udp

go 1.20

require github.com/jackpal/bencode-go v1.0.0
```

---

I tried different UDP trackers and torrent files. I am also certain I haven't made a mistake in setting up the connection.

I am sure I'm missing something important here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I first open a UDP connection and send a connect message to the tracker but receive no response in return." Since this is UDP, it is possible that the response is filtered by your default router. To rule out this possibility, you can run a tracker on localhost. If it still doesn't work, you will know that the problem lies in your code, and you will have the tracker's log to help. If it works, you will have to understand how to open a hole for UDP in your default router, for example using UPnP